# Wien oscillator with amplitude stabilization

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator

Here is Wien oscillator with amplitude stabilization:

[image]

I know how this oscillator works in theory, but I'm interested how it would behave in practice. Voltage at Vout node would be sine wave. If we put some load between Vout and ground, it will affect amplitude of Vout, right?
Is it because of limited output current of opamp (LM741 in this case)?
I simulated this circuit in Multisim. Firstly, I connected 100k resistance on output and I didn't notice any change in amplitude of Vout.
Then I used lower values of resistance, and for example, for resistance of 10 Ohms on output, amplitude of Vout is about 0.13V.
What are applications of Wien oscillator?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to learn about oscillators and the different working principles I recommend to find an answer to the question: "What is the purpose of the diodes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I used lower values of resistance, and for example, for
>   resistance of 10 Ohms on output, amplitude of Vout is about 0.13V.

A 741 is NOT a power amplifier - putting 10 ohms on the output is a recipe for disaster. Read the data sheet...

+/- 25mA is the output short circuit current and it's not recommended for anything like 10 ohms. In the data sheet it talks about the minimum load being 2 kohm to meet other technical values.

> What are applications of Wien oscillator?

The process of learning to read data sheets and understanding op-amps will expose you to many applications and if you think that's an unfair answer then "tough" because questions that solicit opinions are usually closed down.